# Where did Sherlock Holmes music originate?

Tags: sherlock, soundtrack, sherlock-holmes-a-game-of-shadows, sherlock-holmes-2009

I just recently re-watched BBC's Sherlock Holmes, and was thinking back to all of the other Sherlock-type movies I had seen. Then I noticed, all of this music sounds similar (sources below), but Arthur Conan Doyle never composed any music. At what point did we begin to connect this style of music to Sherlock Holmes? I understand that in the books (and most movies) Sherlock was a violinist, but even the non-violin pieces have similar melodies.

**Sources:**

- **(BBC's Sherlock)**
- **(Sherlock Holmes 2)**
- **(Granada TV)**
- **(Veggietales)**

Comment: "Where did this style of music originate" - I think this part of the question is not on topic here, the rest of the question is ok.

Comment: I have edited the question, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modern Sherlock Holmes soundtracks (including [Sherlock Holmes (2009)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0988045/) and [Sherlock Holmes: A Game of Shadows (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1515091/) by Hans Zimmer and [BBC's Sherlock (TV series)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1475582/) by David Arnold and Michael Price) were influenced mostly by Patrick Gowers music for [The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes (1984)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086661/) TV series.

Here's an example:

However, not all Sherlock Holmes movies sound similar. For example, [Mr. Holmes (2015)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3168230/) despite having good old violin sounds way different.