# What is the relationship between the theme songs in Sherlock Holmes (2009 movie) and Sherlock (BBC series)?

Tags: production, sherlock, soundtrack, sherlock-holmes-2009

I've just started binge-watching the BBC series *Sherlock*. The first episode aired 7 months after the release of the movie *Sherlock Holmes*, starring Robert Downey, Jr. The theme songs for the movie and the series were composed by different people - Hans Zimmer for the movie, and Michael Price and David Arnold for the series. Yet both theme songs include a rarely-used instrument, the hammer dulcimer. The hammer dulcimer melodies are reminiscent of each other as well.

Were Michael Price and David Arnold influenced by Hans Zimmer's score? Did Zimmer, Price, and Arnold collaborate or compare notes? Did an executive at the BBC insist that the theme songs should have similar elements? **Is there any explanation for the similar, unusual instrumentation of the two themes?**

*Sherlock Holmes* theme song, by Hans Zimmer:

BBC's *Sherlock* theme song, by Michael Price and David Arnold:

Comment: They were both influenced by an older work according to this: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81728/where-did-sherlock-holmes-music-originate

Comment: @Nolimon Interesting S.E. question and answer! However, the music in that answer does not include the hammer dulcimer that stood out to me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**They were not influenced by Zimmer**

Michael Price and David Arnold answered this in an [interview](https://www.classicalmpr.org/story/2014/03/17/sherlock-bbc-composers-interview):

> **How much of an influence was Hans Zimmer's score from the Sherlock Holmes movie?**
>   
>   
>   Regarding the film...I suppose it's not unusual to have a violin-led approach to the character of Sherlock. It's not unusual for composers to come up with a similar approach to a character, and he was a high-functioning drug user, so there's a bit of madness involved. When we were working on the music for and after the pilot, the Sherlock Holmes film hadn't come out, so it was just one of those things.

Also, about the [Hammered Dulcimer](https://manufacturing.dustystrings.com/blog/hammered-dulcimer-film-scores):

> In "Discombobulate" from Hans Zimmer's score for Sherlock Holmes, the dulcimer doubles the melody, giving it a sharp timbre and adding to the Eastern European folk flair of the music.

So, it's just a coincidence that they use this same exact instrument.

Comment: Thank you for finding this. The coincidence of them BOTH using a hammer dulcimer still seems _very_ odd.

Comment: @BrettFromLA Possibly there's some association between the Sherlock Holmes character and the instrument that would lead them to independently decide to use it? May be worth looking into a bit.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Wow, interesting idea! I heard solo violin in the 1984 TV series "The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes", and that makes sense because Sherlock is a violinist, but I'd have to research hammer dulcimer like you said.

Comment: It's well known that Sherlock Holmes is a violinist. I don't remember if he has a Strad, but he does play the violin often enough in the books. I don't ever recall anything about dulcimers. However, Sherlock *was* an opium addict, and a quick Google search reveals the hammer dulcimer comes from the middle east, as does (did?) opium. So, perhaps that's the connection.

Comment: @WayneWerner Brilliant association.

Comment: @WayneWerner a clarification: Holmes was a cocaine addict, not an opium addict. Cocaine was a common drug and people used it to self medicate pretty much everything, in addition to it being prescribed by doctors. Opium on the other hand was viewed as anti-social and harmful, partly *because* it came from the East and Victorian England didn't want to embrace anything *those* kinds of people did.

Comment: @GreySage Ah! So you're right! I was thinking of when Watson found him in the opium den, but a quick search online reveals that I had conflated his being there (in fact, in possession of opium and a pipe), with him being an addict.

Comment: @WayneWerner Probably the only case ever of "I'm not an addict, I'm just undercover!" being true.